# WordPress custom post formats?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to add custom [post formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) in WordPress?

The default ones cover most use cases for me, but there are 2 additional types I'd like to add ("file" and "slideshow").

So how can I add those two additional formats?

Comment: What do you mean by "formats" exactly, what would they do?

Comment: @Pekka: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats

Comment: You can also use the already-defined "Gallery" for a slideshow, and there are image, video and audio types as well.

Comment: @Arno: I'm already using the gallery type for something else and I know about the other types. I need these two custom formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that cannot be done. The Post Formats were never intended to be extended or added to. Please see the following from [Post Formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) on the WordPress Codex (emphasis mine):

> The Post Formats feature provides a standardized list of formats that
>   are available to all themes that support the feature. Themes are not
>   required to support every format on the list. **New formats cannot be
>   introduced by themes or even plugins.** The standardization of this list
>   provides both compatibility between numerous themes and an avenue for
>   external blogging tools to access this feature in a consistent
>   fashion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use an extension. [Here's one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-post-formats/), there are [many](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=post+format).

Comment: Maybe I'm not following...but all those seem to just add a UI to modifying the current post formats available...not actually create new, custom formats.

Comment: Or if you prefer to code your own, refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats#Adding_Post_Type_Support. It's pretty easy once you get the hang of it.

Comment: It adds the UI and creates the post format. The Wordpress database is quite flexible and abstracted, so it can create the post formats on the fly.